# Cancelling a setInterval delay while it is running in AS2

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs4

Is this possible?
I have a file in which a movie clip is launched when the user roles over another element. To make the user experience more pleasant this happens after a 3 second delay using setInterval. Is there a way of stopping and resetting this time if the user rolls off the element before the 3 seconds is up?

```
var xTimer = setInterval(wait, 3000);
function wait(){
    show('all');
    play('all');
    clearInterval(xTimer);
}
```

Above is the code I have used to set the delay, and below is the code I had assumed would interrupt and reset the timer.

```
invisBtn.onRollOut = function(){
  rollover_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
  stop();
  clearInterval(xTimer());
  trace('off');
}
```

Any help on this would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, the setInterval & clearInterval functions use a Number variable to work.

setInterval() returns a Number variable, and clearInterval() takes that Number in parameter to remove the previous started interval. Here you seem to keep the interval ID inside a function variable instead of a Number one.

Thus, `clearInterval(xTimer());` should in reality be `clearInterval(xTimer)`; (without the parenthesis after xTimer).

And secondly, so you can use it in the invisBtn.onRollOut function, just be sure that the xTimer variable is scoped correctly (not inside a function where the invisBtn.onRollOut isn't also), and not on different keyframes of the timeline (timeline keyframes in Flash tends to forget the code you've written on it as soon as the reading head passes onto a new keyframe of the layer which has the code on it).

Feel free to ask more details if you need !